# What are the rules for applying for the same fellowship (scholarship) after being rejected?

Tags: research-process, application, funding, rejection

I have been applying for scholarships and fellowships for a few years, sometimes I have been successful, other times not. Last year I worked a lot to prepare the project and invested all of my time and efforts in it, however the competition was strong and I got rejected after the interview. This year I am planning to apply again but I have found little information or tips for repeat applications. For example, how am I supposed to show personal or professional growth, should the recommenders be the same, how different should the proposal be and so on. Are there any rules when it comes to applying for the same fellowship (grant) for a second time? What is the success rate? Is is reasonable to hope I can get funding when I was rejected once. Could someone maybe share their experience.

Comment: What kind of fellowships are you talking about?  Why do you think you need to show "personal growth"?

Answer (score 1):

This may be more of a long comment than an answer.

Much of what you ask about depends on the specifics of the fellowship/grant you are applying to. Many (most?) fellowships are limited to the X best candidates. In this case, the fact that you did not get it does not mean you did something wrong, simply that there are other candidates that are better. In these cases I don't think "personal growth" is expected, you simply need to be better than the other candidates. There is also an element of luck, since some years may have stronger competing candidates than others.

This does not mean you should not try to strengthen your application/interview.

The success rate depends on the specific fellowship obviously.